# How to write Custom Assert?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, mfc, assert

We need an application, in release build we need assert and we would like to develop something like XXX_ASSERT but the problem is in MFC ASSERT can take any booleanExpression as an argument and evaluate this but if we write our custom assert e.g. MY_ASSERT than how to achieve that custom assert will evaluate any booleanExpression.

```
#include<afxwin.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void abort()
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Test"));
}
#define MY_ASSERT(BoolCondition) do { if (!(BoolCondition)) { abort(); } } while (0)
class CAge:public CObject
{
public:
    int m_nAge;
    CAge(int age)
    {
        m_nAge = age;
    }
};
class MyFrame:public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    MyFrame()
    {
        Create(0,_T("Hello"));
    }
    void OnPaint()
    {
        CPaintDC d(this);
        CBrush r;
        r.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(25,200,152));

        d.SelectObject(&r);
        d.Rectangle(100,100,250,250);
        r.DeleteObject();
        CAge *pAge;// = new CAge(21);
        MY_ASSERT(pAge);
    }
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyFrame, CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
class MyApp:public CWinApp
{
    int InitInstance()
    {
        MyFrame *p = new MyFrame();
        p->ShowWindow(3);
        m_pMainWnd = p;
        return 1;
    }
};
MyApp a;
```

Answer (score 4):

The straighforward approach should work just fine for any Boolean expression:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MY_ASSERT(BoolCondition) do { if (!(BoolCondition)) { abort(); } } while (0)
```

Comment: In MFC assert, argument can be anything like int or object of class but in MY_ASSERT which argument will be. It would be great if you provide me example.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why the 1-iteration loop around the conditional?

Comment: @MehulDonga This macro will work with any `int`, and it will work with any class that has any kind of implicit conversion to `bool`. I can not imagine the MFC assert to work with any class that is not prepared to be tested?

Comment: @ChristianRau That's standard best-practice for macros so that you can use them in any context, for example within an `if`. To see why it is necessary, put the assert in the `if` and give the `if` an `else`.

Comment: @SegFault I guessed that, but wouldn't a simple block (`{}`) have sufficed?

Comment: @ChristianRau No, because then in some cases you would have to call/use the macro without the semikolon, for example within a double-nested `if`.

Comment: @SegFault Hah, indeed! Thanks for the clarification. Coming from C++ I don't have much experience with macros used as functions.

Comment: Hi Seg Fault this solution is working in debug version only. This is not working in release version. How to get it works in release ?

Comment: @MehulDonga That's weird, the standard C `assert` doesn't work in release, but `abort` should always work, and this self-written macro too.

Comment: Hi Seg Fault Please have a look at the code I put it in my question. I am running this application in release mode and I not able to triggered the MY_ASSERT macro and abort() function.I have tryed with user define name like abort1() even its not call in release version.

Comment: Have you tried something else to terminate the application, for example `exit()` or `_exit()` instead of `abort()`? Perhaps the signal corresponding to `abort` is blocked.

Comment: Well, the macro itself is ok, it sure does the right thing here on Unix. Btw, you should not try to define a function named `abort()` because that's a macro in `stdlib.h`. Also `exit()` might not work because it implicitly calls all global destructors, which might hang; I have never programmed under Windows and can't say whether that is a typical/expected issue.

Comment: I have also tried without defining abort() function.May this will be issues in windows.Thank you Seg Fault for the help.

Comment: @MehulDonga Looking at your code the macro probably works perfectly fine. It's just that in release mode pointers are usually not initialized to zero, instead unitialized pointers just contain garbage (i.e. point to a random memory location). So checking `MY_ASSERT(pAge)` right after `pAge`'s declaration (and without any initialization) will most probably result in `true`. Why don't you just test it with `MY_ASSERT(false)`?

Comment: I want achieve same as we can achieve in ASSERT, In ASSERT if We pass any expression like ASSERT(pAge) then its triggered so How can i achieve this ?

Comment: @MehulDonga No, in release mode it isn't. That's what I'm saying in the above comment. In realease mode this pointer is **not** `0` (which is the only resulting in an assertion faliure), or rather it may or may not, if **you** didn't set it to `0`. This doesn't have nything to do with your particular assert implementation (and wouldn't work for MFC's either), but with the fact that unitialized variables are, well, uninitialized. So replace `CAge *pAge;` with `CAge *pAge = 0;` and see what magically happens.

Comment: @SegFault: Your macro is pretty good, one thing you might want to add to it is something like `std::fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d Assertion failed: %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, #BoolCondition);` so that you get a nice message